# Why am I getting these errors like Unclassifiable statement at 1 and unexpected junk , etc. in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I'm just starting out with Fortran and tried to write a basic program but have been getting tons of errors that I don't understand. Please check the following. I've referred to other such questions but to no avail.

```
    program roots

    real a,b,c
    real disc
    real root1,root2

    write (*,*) , "Please provide a, b and c"
    read (*,*) ,a,b,c
    disc = b**2 -4.0*a*c

    if disc < 0
    print *,"No real roots"

    else if disc = 0
    print *,"Equal roots"
    root1 = -b/2
    print *,"root is :" ,root1

    else 
    print *,"2 real roots"
    2*root1 = -b + sqrt(b**2 - 4.0*a*c)
    2*root2 = -b - sqrt(b**2 - 4.0*a*c)
    print *,"root 1 is:" , root1
    print *,"root 2 is:" , root2

    end roots
```

errors:

```sh
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)

Error: Unexpected junk after ELSE statement at (1)

Error: Unexpected ELSE statement at (1)

Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)

Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)

Error: Expecting END PROGRAM statement at (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were mulitple mistakes in your code.

First of all: always use `implicit none` otherwise undefined variables might have implicit data types which is hard to debug.

Your `if .. end if` block had multiple mistakes. Compare both codes.

```pascal
program roots

  implicit none

  real a,b,c
  real disc
  real root1,root2

  print *, "Please provide a, b and c"
  read (*,*)  a,b,c
  disc = b**2 -4.0*a*c

  if (disc < 0) then
    print *, "No real roots"

  else if (disc == 0) then
    print *, "Equal roots"
    root1 = -b/2
    print *, "root is :", root1

  else
    print *,"2 real roots"
    root1 = (-b + sqrt(b**2 - 4.0*a*c)) / 2
    root2 = (-b - sqrt(b**2 - 4.0*a*c)) / 2
    print *, "root 1 is:", root1
    print *, "root 2 is:", root2
  end if

end program
```